# Replace NA with values in another row of same column for each group in r

Tags: r

I need to replace the NA's of each row with non NA's values of different row for a given column for each group

let say sample data like:

```
id   name
 1     a
 1     NA
 2     b
 3     NA
 3     c
 3     NA
```

desired output:

```
id   name
 1     a
 1     a
 2     b
 3     c
 3     c
 3     c
```

Is there a way to perform this in r ?

Comment: if each `id` always has at least one non-`NA`, you can just use any last-observation-carried-forward function, like one from `zoo`: `zoo::na.locf(df1[with(df1, order(id, name)), ])` using @akruns data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to do this.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Grouped by 'id', we replace the 'name' with the non-NA value in 'name'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[, name:= name[!is.na(name)][1L] , by = id]
df1
#   id name
#1:  1    a
#2:  1    a
#3:  2    b
#4:  3    c
#5:  3    c
#6:  3    c
```

NOTE: Here I assumed that there is only a single unique non-NA value within each 'id' group.

Or another option would be to join the dataset with the `unique` rows of the data after we `order` by 'id' and 'name'.

```
 setDT(df1)
 df1[unique(df1[order(id, name)], by='id'), on='id', name:= i.name][]
 #   id name
 #1:  1    a
 #2:  1    a
 #3:  2    b
 #4:  3    c
 #5:  3    c
 #6:  3    c
```

NOTE: The `on` is only available with the devel version of `data.table`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), name = c("a", 
NA, "b", NA, "c", NA)), .Names = c("id", "name"),
class = "data.frame",    row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is an approach using `dplyr`.  From the data frame `x` we group by `id` and replace `NA` with the relevant values.  I am assuming one unique value of `name` per `id`.

```
x <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, rep(3,3)), 
 name = c("a", NA, "b", NA, "c", NA), stringsAsFactors=F)

require(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(name = unique(name[!is.na(name)]))

Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
Groups: id

#  id name
#1  1    a
#2  1    a
#3  2    b
#4  3    c
#5  3    c
#6  3    c
```

Answer (score 3):

Base R

```
d<-na.omit(df)
transform(df,name=d$name[match(id,d$id)])
```

again assuming one unique value of name per id (forces it)