# Replacing NA with another value in same column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to replace NA with proceeding value in the same column using dplyr package, But I am not getting results. Below is script I am using.

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv",header=T,na.strings=c("","NULL"))

data$ID <- paste(data$ID1, data$ID2, sep='_')

data$End.Date <- as.Date(data$End.Date, "%d-%b-%y")

data1 <- data[order(data$ID, data$End.Date),]

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  fill(Start.date, .direction = 'up') %>% 
  fill(Start.date, .direction = 'down')
```

Also please see below data file which I am using in above script. Can anyone please help me to know why NA is not replaced in using above syntax. Script is not throwing error

```
ID1 ID2 Start date  End Date
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    1-Jan-17
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   2-Oct-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   2-Oct-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   3-Jul-16
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    4-Dec-16
1031    40035   18-Jul-16   4-Sep-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   4-Sep-16
1031    40043   23-Jan-17   5-Feb-17
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    5-Feb-17
1031    40042   18-Jan-17   5-Feb-17
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   5-Jun-16
1031    40044   17-Feb-17   5-Mar-17
1031    40043   23-Jan-17   5-Mar-17
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   6-Nov-16
1031    40035   NULL    7-Aug-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   7-Aug-16
1031    40036   NULL    7-Aug-16
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    8-Jan-17
1031    40045   28-Mar-17   9-Apr-17
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   9-Oct-16
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   9-Oct-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   10-Jul-16
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    11-Dec-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   11-Sep-16
1031    40043   23-Jan-17   12-Feb-17
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   12-Jun-16
1031    40043   23-Jan-17   12-Mar-17
1031    40044   17-Feb-17   12-Mar-17
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   13-Nov-16
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    13-Nov-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   14-Aug-16
1031    40035   18-Jul-16   14-Aug-16
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    15-Jan-17
1031    40045   28-Mar-17   16-Apr-17
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   16-Oct-16
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   16-Oct-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   17-Jul-16
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    18-Dec-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   18-Sep-16
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   18-Sep-16
1031    40043   23-Jan-17   19-Feb-17
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   19-Jun-16
1031    40043   23-Jan-17   19-Mar-17
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    20-Nov-16
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   20-Nov-16
1031    40035   18-Jul-16   21-Aug-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   21-Aug-16
1031    40039   9-Jan-17    22-Jan-17
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    22-Jan-17
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   22-May-16
1031    40045   28-Mar-17   23-Apr-17
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   23-Oct-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   23-Oct-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   24-Jul-16
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    25-Dec-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   25-Sep-16
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   25-Sep-16
1031    40043   23-Jan-17   26-Feb-17
1031    40044   17-Feb-17   26-Feb-17
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   26-Jun-16
1031    40043   23-Jan-17   26-Mar-17
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   27-Nov-16
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    27-Nov-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   28-Aug-16
1031    40035   18-Jul-16   28-Aug-16
1031    40038   7-Nov-16    29-Jan-17
1031    40042   18-Jan-17   29-Jan-17
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   29-May-16
1031    40037   12-Sep-16   30-Oct-16
1031    40036   8-Jul-16    31-Jul-16
1031    40033   15-Feb-16   31-Jul-16
1031    40035   18-Jul-16   31-Jul-16
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace NA with values in another row of same column for each group in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879390/replace-na-with-values-in-another-row-of-same-column-for-each-group-in-r)

Comment: I just checked your code, and the resulting `data1 ` has no NA's in it.

Comment: I think the more canonical dupe in this case is this one: [Using dplyr window-functions to make trailing values (fill in NA values)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23340150/903061), but I agree with ssp3nc3r that the NA-replacing code looks fine, OP should work on the importing code and make sure NA values are present where they should be.

Comment: @Gregor, Thanks a lot for your reply able to replace NA with using information which you shared.

Answer (score 1):

The zoo library has a great function for this called na.locf()

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

data <- read.csv("data.csv",header=T,na.strings=c("","NULL"))

data$ID <- paste(data$ID1, data$ID2, sep='_')

data$End.Date <- as.Date(data$End.Date, "%d-%b-%y")

data1 <- data[order(data$ID, data$End.Date),]

data1 <- data1 %>% 
         group_by(ID) %>% 
         mutate(Start.Date = ifelse(is.na(Start.Date),na.locf(Start.Date, na.rm = FALSE), Start.Date))
```

Comment: It's unusual to run `na.locf` inside an `ifelse(is.na())` construct. OP is trying to use `tidyr::fill`, which is very similar to `zoo::na.locf` - I'm not sure that replacing `fill` with `na.locf` is likely to fix any problems...

Comment: @Matt, Thanks for sharing script. I tried your script, was able to replace data for missing values in start.date, but unfortunately it changed format of column to numeric. Not sure why it changed format of column.