# Wrap around Function for the transform() function for Replacing NAs with values in another row of same column for each group in r

Tags: r, function

My question builds on the answers found here: [Replace NA with values in another row of same column for each group in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879390/replace-na-with-values-in-another-row-of-same-column-for-each-group-in-r)

I found the solutions for replacing NAs with values in another row of same column group(e.g., setDT(df1)[, name:= name[!is.na(name)][1L] , by = id]) worked brilliantly when I applied it to my real data and fake data:

```
 df<-data.frame(a=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"), b=c("yes", "yes", NA, "No", NA, "No", "yes", "yes", NA))

 df
  a    b
1 a  yes
2 a  yes
3 a <NA>
4 b   No
5 b <NA>
6 b   No
7 c  yes
8 c  yes
9 c <NA>
 dfc<-setDT(df)[, b:= b[!is.na(b)][1L] , by = a]
 dfc
 dfc
   a   b
1: a yes
2: a yes
3: a yes
4: b  No
5: b  No
6: b  No
7: c yes
8: c yes
9: c yes
```

Now, I've tried to write a wrap around function so I can switch out 'a' and 'b' for alternative data frames and variables, but unfortunately, I can't get it to work. It comes back with an error "object 'a' not found".

```
 Fill_NAs_WherePossible<-function(df,var1,var2){
  df_b<-setDT(df)[, var1:= var1[!is.na(var1)][1L] , by = var2]
   return(df_b)  
 }
 dfd<-Fill_NAs_WherePossible(df,b,a)
 Error: object 'a' not found
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Cheers!